# Render topojson mesh in D3 as distinct paths

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, topojson

I have code like:

```
d3.json("topo-census-regions.json", function(error, topoJ) {
    g.append("path")
        .datum(topojson.mesh(topoJ, topoJ.objects.divis, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
        .attr("class", "division-borders")
        .attr("d", path);
});
```

It works, basically. (This is pretty much straight from Bostock's [zoom demo](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590), just using a different source file.)

My problem is that the boundaries between census regions render out as a single SVG path. TopoJson's `mesh` method collapses all shared internal boundaries into a single compound path. But I need to render different parts of the path with different styles.

For a visual reference, see [this](http://www2.census.gov/geo/pdfs/maps-data/maps/reference/us_regdiv.pdf).

The boundary between "Pacific" and "Mountain" within the "Western" division should be one path element, the boundary between "West North Central" and "East North Central" should be another, etc. I could manufacture these paths manually in Illustrator fairly easily but need to be able to do this programmatically across a large data set. I want the efficient de-duplication that `mesh` performs, but with continuous segments as separate elements.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: An image about what you need at the end could be very helpful.

Comment: thanks, added a link.

Comment: Creating a fiddle would be more helpful but anyways where is the actual problem on this? Just use the usual outline. And on top of that add meshes to the specific areas. Should be very easy. Here I have done the same thing http://arda-maps.org/ages/third/ click on Region on the button. Is this what you want?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm wanting to do the same thing.

Comment: @Ian For one-time use I wound up going through them in a loop, manually picking out id's on the original files. For example: g.append("path").datum(topojson.mesh(topoJ, topoJ.objects.divis, function(a, b) {
    return a !== b && a.id === "1";
  }); I am still looking for a general solution for future reference.

Comment: Well you could use .data(topojson.feature(topoJ, topoJ.objects.divis) to achieve this as described in this example http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/ . The reason I wanted to use mesh though was because I didn't like the look of the outer most boundaries. However, I gave in and used .feature because, like you I needed to do selective styling.